# How do I add force in all directions on point of touch or mouse click?

Tags: unity

I wanna add a force on the point of player touch. Basically when player touches a point it release force in all directions and all sprite in its range get effected and start moving.
[image]

What is the right way to go about it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing. I dont have any clue how to go about it. I tried point effector but I that doesnt work.

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs on [AddExplosionForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html)?

Comment: doesnt work on 2d

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of using Empty GameObject that spawns on mouse click but instantly destroy. That game object has a ForceOnClick script to detect every object in its range, and call function from a script named Force in that object.

```
public List<Collider2D> AffectedObjects = new List<Collider2D>();
public LayerMask EffectLayer;
public float magnitude = 10;
    
void SetAttractedObjects()
    {
        AffectedObjects = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, effectionRadius, EffectLayer).ToList();// can be optimized
    }

    void AttractObjects()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AffectedObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            AffectedObjects[i].GetComponent<Force>().Push(this);
        }
    
    }
```

You need to put all the object that will affected by the gravity to a layer and set it to this script. These two functions will be called from update. You can also use gizmo to see how big the radius from editor, with:

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, effectionRadius);
    }
```

On the affected object, you can make a Force script that push object away.

```
Transform m_transform;
Collider2D m_collider;
Rigidbody2D m_rigdibody;
ForceOnClick currentFoc;

public void Push(ForceOnClick foc)
    {
        Vector2 pushDir = (Vector2)foc.planetTransform.position - m_rigdibody.position;
        m_rigdibody.AddForce(pushDir.normalized * -foc.magnitude * force * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if (currentFoc == null) 
        {
            currentFoc = foc;
        }  
    }
```

After applying the force, you can destroy the game object